# Is there a more terse way of writing if-statements in C#?

Tags: c#

Perhaps there is and I don't know about it and if so I would gladly like to be enlightened. I would like to be able to using something similar to the ?: operator but without having to include the : and without having to assign the result to a variable, like so:

```
q?r();
```

which  would be semantically identically to

```
if (q)
{
    r();
}
```

Edit: I should've expressed myself clearer. I'm looking for a way to get rid of the if's and else's and express the conditional statement with a more functional style.

Cheers,
/Christian

Comment: For "more terse" read "less legible/easy to follow".

Comment: @middaparka: So, by that logic, readability increases linearly with the length of code?

Comment: @Adam Robinson Obviously not (otherwise COBOL would be the most readable language in the world). My point is that once your code begins to look like an entry in obfuscated code competition, then perhaps some issues may lie ahead on the maintenance front. :-)

Comment: @middaparka: Certainly true; I was just getting at the fact that sometimes "more terse" is "more readable" :)

Comment: @middaparka: I agree that conciseness is not desirable at the expense of readability, but I think the question mark above is sufficiently legible as it has the same meaning as in human language namely: is this statement true?

Answer (score 5):

```
if (q) r();
```

That's about as terse as you can get with it.

Comment: Nope, you can still remove whitespace: `if(q)r();` :D

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can save writing `if` statements by using LINQ.

For example, instead of:

```
int CountItemsLargerThanFive(IEnumerable<int> collection)
{
   int count = 0;
   foreach (var item in collection)
   {
      if (item > 5)
      {
         count++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

You can write:

```
int CountItemsLargerThanFive(IEnumerable<int> collection)
{
   return collection.Count(item => item > 5);
}
```

No `if`'s!

And there are many other cases in which control structures such as `if` can be replaced by LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a single statement, you can omit the brackets and write it on a single line:

```
if (q) r();
```

Normally it's more readable to have the condition and the code on separate lines, and always include the brackets, but if both the condition and the code are simple, the readability should not be a problem.

Example:

```
if (line > 0) builder.AppendLine();
```

as an alternative to:

```
if (line > 0) {
  builder.AppendLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, stick with the obvious route.

**For fun**, here's a way to use the conditional operator like you'd wanted, with delegates (please don't do this):

```
(q ? (Action)r : () => { })();
```

which looks slightly nicer if there were a genuine `else`:

```
(q ? (Action)trueAction : falseAction)();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also use : `x ?? 0`
this is the null checking

Comment: The question has nothing to do with null checking.